# Can any one please tell, about the use of AFNetworking. Then it support all xcode version or not?

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

I download one example from [this link](http://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/master/Example). Currently I am using xcode 4.2. It shows `AFNetworkReachabilityStatus` as undeclared variable. Please give any link to learn `AFNetworking`.

Comment: Try using an older version (tagged) https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/1.x/Example

Comment: Check this http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/

Comment: @Wain:Thanks now I got it.

Comment: check this issue da http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656315/which-datatype-will-return-the-value-37-961498-as-it-is-double-dint-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different versions of AFNetworking.

Latest AFNetworking [2.0](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/) and higher requires Xcode 5, targeting either iOS 6.0 and above, or Mac OS 10.8 Mountain Lion (64-bit with modern Cocoa runtime) and above.

For compatibility with iOS 5 or Mac OS X 10.7, use the **[1.x release](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/1.x)**.

For compatibility with iOS 4.3 or Mac OS X 10.6, use the **[0.10.x release](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/0.10.x)**.

Now if you want to support ios 4.3 or greater use 0.10 release.

[AFNetworking Doc](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/)

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. I download the IOS 4.3 version AFNetworking. I solve some error in that. Still I've one error. Can you please tell what I want to do now. This error only I got   @synthesize  username = _username;

Comment: and for username you can set `@property (nonatomic,strong)` in **.h** file.

Comment: Thanks It works well. But compile it successfully but when loading image in Tableview I got crash due to this"[AFImageRequestOperation setAutomaticallyInflatesResponseImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a48f00
2013-10-22 19:01:59.953 AFNetworking iOS Example[4248:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AFImageRequestOperation setAutomaticallyInflatesResponseImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a48f00'". Please tell solution for this

Comment: :Download image from url for visible cell.imageView in the UITableViewCell. Now I got the output. Thanks to help me