# AFNetworkReachabilityStatus Is returned as undeclared variable what issue is it?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

AFNetworkReachability Status is returned as undeclared variable. why does this problem comes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of xcode do you use? I may be version problem.

Comment: Then, Ya this is a version problem.

Comment: Ok but solution ? Can you help ?

Comment: can you please share the link link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517002/can-any-one-please-tell-about-the-use-of-afnetworking-then-it-support-all-xcod