# Which dataType will return the value (37.961498) as it is ? Double didn't work

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, type-conversion

Which dataType will return the value (37.961498) as it is?

I am working in MapView. Where, at present I am setting annotation and hence I have to set CLLocationCoordinate2DMake with some lat and lng parsed from googleAPI (Eg:lat = "37.9615000" and lng = "60.5566000") . I have the values in string, hence I converted the sting to double and then assigned But it didn't help. Please some one help me.

```
   double int1=[num1s floatValue];
    double int2=[num2s floatValue];
   NSLog(@" %f %f ",int1,int2);
    annotation.coordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(int1, int2);
```

actual values are: 37.9615000,60.5566000
Values I get in NSLog:   37.961498, 60.556599

Thanks in advance.

More explanation and reason why I need exact value:

I need to set annotation for china With its lat and lan ( lat = "53.5609740";
        lng = "134.7728099")

But while converting again from string the value changes

[image]

Comment: [What every Computer Scientist should know about floating point arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: What is your problem, by the way?  Why do you need exact results?

Comment: to make the annotations .since a minute value will change the annotation i need the exact results.

Comment: But you never had an "exact" result to begin with.  Your values start as float and will never be "exact".

Comment: (Read the above reference.)

Answer (score 2):

When converting a `string` to a `double` you should be using `doubleValue` instead of `floatValue`

```
double int1=[num1s doubleValue];
double int2=[num2s doubleValue];
NSLog(@" %f %f ",int1,int2);
annotation.coordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(int1, int2);
```

also not critical but I wouldn't recommend naming your doubles as int1 and int2 that is likely to cause you confusion at some point

Comment: And the NSLog is : 5.356097e+01 1.347728e+02  :( dint help i need to get 53.5609740 134.7728099 .

Comment: @SiddarthHailstorm -- You might want to change your format to show all the digits -- `NSLog(@" %20.16f %20.16f", int1, int2);`

Comment: Its now : 53.5609740000000016 134.7728098999999986 i need 53.5609740 134.7728099 since a minute value will change the annotation. Also another question for you, for NSLOg its okay ! How to change "annotation.coordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(int1, int2);"  ???

Comment: @SiddarthHailstorm - Why do you need to change the 2DMake statement?  (And what do you think *can* be changed?)

Comment: i does nt need to change the 2DMake statement ! ya lemme explain clearly to you. Actually im parsing the search string to google api and getting the results in a Dictionary. And then i am putting all the dictionaries into an array. Later on im getting the specific dictionary by using for loop. then i get the value of address and value of name from the dictionary using the key. Now i am storing the name,lat,lan in string and i need to convert the string to use it  in annotation.coordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(int1, int2);  in order to annotate it .

Comment: When you are using WGS84 latitude and longitude values and you get down to 6 digits beyond the decimal place you're dealing with centimeters. For all intents and purposes 53.560974 and 53.560975 are the same place. Parse it once it comes in from the API and use that value through the rest of your code.
Also, if you are doing this in iOS 6, Google say you're not allowed to put data from their search APIs on to anyone else's maps (i.e. not onto Apple Maps)

Answer (score 2):

```
annotation.coordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([nums doubleValue], [int2 doubleValue]);
```

Try this

Answer (score 1):

```
double int1=[num1s floatValue];
double int2=[num2s floatValue];
NSLog(@" %0.7f %0.7f ",int1,int2);
annotation.coordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(int1, int2);
```

Read [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265) for more info.

Comment: your code returns : 53.5609741210937500 134.7728118896484375 what i need is just 53.5609740 134.7728099 . Thanks

Comment: It's should work. Please check again which format you are using, when printing numbers.

Comment: Sorry buddy ! Its done now ! its printing exactly but how to implement this in coordinate?  annotation.coordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(int1, int2); ? how will i add those %0.7 in my code? can u tell me the syntax ?

Comment: You can do this: uiLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %0.7f %0.7f ", annotation.coordinate.latitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude];